# Very low perfomance in Grid View

Tags: gridview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have recently build a page that makes some calculations from elements that are in the header and in the left of table and puts the results in a grid view.

Everything works ok, but the performance is just horrible. More than that it's unusable on a phone (I'm currently working with a Lumia 1020).
Starting with the problems, it has a terrible memory leak (maybe it needs 100MB of RAM and all of it it isn't liberated after going back or somewhere else in the app).

Then, the loading time is very long 6-7 seconds if I load all the elements in the same thread, if I load them in the background, the user can easily see that the elements are getting loaded in the grid view, and during this time it is unusable.

After the loading is complete, the scrolling is quite laggy. Sometimes even it doesn't respond to the user. The scrolling of the top, left and middle elements are synchronised, but when moving the middle grid view, the others need like half of a second to reach the same offset. When it is happened on the other way, it takes a second or more to get the same offset in the scroll and it happens with a jump (not smoothly).

I have like 20x50 elements to load and calculate.

Below are the codes:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid x:Name="tbMain" Width="75" Height="75" Margin="1.5,1.5,-1.5,1.5" DoubleTapped="tbHMain_DoubleTapped">
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tbMainHeaderTable" Text="some text"
               Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
               Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
</Grid>

<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Top" ViewChanged="Top_ViewChanged" Margin="0,1.5,1.5,0"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <ListView x:Name="gridTop" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1.5,1.5,1.5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              DataContext="{Binding listFocal}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTapEnabled="False"
              IsHoldingEnabled="False">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <GridViewItem Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="75" Height="75"
                              Background="{StaticResource DarkGreyThemeColor}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTop" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GoldenThemeStyle}"/>
                </GridViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>

<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Left" ViewChanged="Left_ViewChanged" Margin="0,1.5,0,1.5"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

    <ListView x:Name="gridLeft" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTapEnabled="False"
              IsHoldingEnabled="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridViewItem Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75"
                              Height="75" Background="{StaticResource DarkGreyThemeColor}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbLeft" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GoldenThemeStyle}"/>
                </GridViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ScrollViewer>

<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Middle" ViewChanged="Middle_ViewChanged" Margin="1.5"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

    <GridView x:Name="gridMiddle" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTapEnabled="False"
              IsHoldingEnabled="False">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="28" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="75" Height="75"
                      Background="{StaticResource MediumDarkGreyThemeColor}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbResult" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

```
private void Middle_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
Top.ChangeView(Middle.HorizontalOffset, null, null, true);
Left.ChangeView(null, Middle.VerticalOffset, null, true);
}

private void Left_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
Middle.ChangeView(null, Left.VerticalOffset, null, true);
}

private void Top_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
Middle.ChangeView(Top.HorizontalOffset, null, null, true);
}

private void tbMain_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
Middle.ChangeView(0, 0, null, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load so many items then you should use incremental loading i.e. load items when user nears the item to be shown. Check [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manishkdwivedi/implement-isupportincrementalloading-in-windows-store-apps/) for this.

Comment: Thank you fro your answer and some questions about incremental loading before I start coding:

1-. If the user scrolls fast the gridview, the items are loaded fast enough?
2-. If the each element value or what contains changes in the origin IncrementalLoadingList, when the gridview is in certain position, these items are refreshed in first order or not?

Comment: 1. If data is loading from API then it depends on internet connection speed and if your list is loading from locally saved data then it's quite fast.          2. For this type of incremental loading you need to use ObservableCollection or any other collection which implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface itself by default so every change made in original collection is automatically reflected in GridView used.

Comment: Hi, Rohit. As always thank you for your responses.
1-. Data is loaded directly in the application; a list is made at the beginning of the App and then it is used in the gridview.
2-. I am using a ObservableCollection. 

`code` public static ObservableCollection<string> myList;`code`